# Converting Mootools 1.1 Ajax call to Mootools 1.3

Tags: javascript, mootools

I've got a Mootools 1.1 class here and i want to turn it running in Mootools 1.3. 
The onComplete functions somehow cannot send the "data" result to the processResults function. The Ajax call is working and i get an JSON result. Only thing is the processResults function is not receiving it. 
I guess it has something to do with the this.processResults.bind(this) call.

```
processSearch: function () {

        var url = this.options.url;
        var ajaxRequest = new Request.HTML({
    url: url,
            method: 'post',
            data: 'arg1=123',
            onRequest: this.requestSearch.bind(this),
            onComplete: this.processResults.bind(this)
        }).send()
    }
},

processResults: function (data) {
   console.log(data); // data not defined here :(
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you expect JSON, use `Request.JSON()` instead. otherwise, your code seems correct, given that `this` points to the class instance in `processSearch` itself and not something else.

Comment: I have to go to get some sleep!